# How to extract contents from WMI file in python?

Tags: python, wmi

I have WMI-files on my hdd, which I can open using some supporting tools (LogReader). In wmi-files, I have some report information as text module. I want to convert these files into .txt, .xml or some other datatype, which is suitable to use in python. So, I can use the information for further tasks. I tried to extract contents of WMI-Files in python but I couldn't accomplish it.

Is there any way to solve this problem of mine?

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Why doesn't https://pypi.org/project/WMI/ work?

Comment: I tried it but I couldn't use my WMI-File, which I want to open/read. It was more about getting informations from my WIN32-Serial Port.

I got about 200 WMI-Files on my hdd. I really don't know which command I should use to extract contant of my files. Is there a way to do it?